# Android Studio Preview Elements not clickable

Tags: android, android-studio

I really love how convenient and easy it is to just click on your elements on the preview for easy navigation and edit your selected element. but on the recent update of Android Studio, I noticed that every time I add/change a background on a layout, I can't anymore click the element/s in the preview screen. I really have to scroll on the xml and find that element. which is time consuming.

If you have experienced unable to click elements in the preview screen and got a solution, I'd be glad to try it. Thanks!

although one solution is to just restart Studio. willing to try other suggestions.

Comment: Even I face this issue some times ,I got nothing better solution than restarting android studio